# angularjs 2 and data won't pass to the params route

Tags: angular, service, routes, parameters

been working an angular 2 app where click on a link, it goes to the page with the params with the data on it. I think I mostly understand how it is done but there is an error that preventing my data from showing up onto the detail page when I click on a link on the list page. Can someone help fix this problem, I been stuck on this all day. Basically, when I click on a link on the list page and it goes to the details page. The data isn't showing up. Not sure what to fix.

film-list.component

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
    import { FilmService } from '../film.service';
    import { Film } from "../film";

    @Component({
      template: `
      <h1>List of Films</h1>
      <p>Films:</p>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let film of films ">
         <a [routerLink]="['/films', film.id]">{{film.title}}</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <p *ngIf="films.length > 3">There are many vietnamese films to learn about!</p>
    `
    })

    //Component class
    export class FilmListComponent implements OnInit {

      public films: Film[] = [];//******try like this
      constructor(private filmService: FilmService) {
      }

      getFilms() {
        this.filmService.getFilms().then((films: Film[]) => this.films = films);
      }

      ngOnInit(): any {
        this.getFilms()
      }
    }

film-details


    import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FilmService } from '../film.service';
import { Film } from "../film";

@Component ({
  selector: 'film-details',
  template:
    `
<h1>Film Information</h1>
<h1>Rating: 5/5</h1>
     <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300&fm=png" width="100">
     <p>Summary information</p>




<div *ngIf="film">
<h2>{{film.title}}</h2>
<p>{{film.summary}}</p>
</div>
`,
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})

//Component class
export class FilmDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public sub: any;
  public films: Film[] = [];
  film: Film;

  constructor(private filmService: FilmService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  //Load data
  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to route params
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params ['id'];

      //retrieve the film id
      this.filmService.getFilms(id).then(film => this.film = film);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Clean sub to avoid memory leak
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

film-services

```
  import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

    import { Film } from './film';
    import { FILMS } from './mock-films';

    @Injectable()
    export class FilmService {
      getFilms(): Promise<Film[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(FILMS)
      }

      getFilm(id: number): Promise<Film> {
        return this.getFilms()
          .then(films => films.find(film => film.id === id));
      }
    }
```

mock-data

```
import { Film } from './film';

//storing the data in array
export const FILMS: Film[] = [
  {id:11, title: 'pokemon', summary:'great'},
  {id:12, title: 'naruto', summary: 'good'},
  {id:13, title: 'bleach', summary: 'meh'},
  {id:14, title: 'one piece', summary: 'not bad'}
];
app.routes.ts

....
// Route Configuration
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'films', component: FilmListComponent},
  { path: 'films/:id', component: FilmDetailsComponent}
];
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vietnam</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- MDL CSS library  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- MDL JavaScript library  -->
    <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Material Design Icons  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <!-- Custom Style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <!-- ./index.html  -->
    <!-- need to show up basic route -->
    <base href="/">
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no `film` property in your component. You need that

Comment: are you talking about the details components? how would I add that?

Comment: Just add a `film: Film` property right under `public films: Film[] = []`

Comment: So I added film: Film; under the public films: Film[] = [] and it didn't work. any other things I can try.

Comment: Youre component is using `findFilmById` but your method in the service is `getFilm`. Look in your console are you getting any errors?

Comment: Also the i params always come in as strings. So if you want to get it in number form, you need to use `+params['id']`. Notice the `+`

Comment: honestly, there aren't any error I see in the console. I honestly willing to try anything to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see in your code:

1. Are you sure you are importing `FilmService` from the correct path? You are importing from `../film.service`, but you are stating that the file name is `film-services` (Notice you are using hyphen for the file name)
2. Assuming you are importing from `../film-service`, you should change `findFilmById` method to `getFilms`. Also you need to change `.subscribe` to `.then` because `getFilms` return Promise instead of `Observable`

Comment: film-services is a typo, it is import from film-service. Anyways, I changed it to getFilms and .changed .subscribe to .then. The data is still not showing up but there is improvement as the id params now shows up in the url when I travel to the page so that something. I'll will update the code. Anything else I can change??

Comment: like @peeskillet said, you need property 'film' inside your 'FilmDetailsComponent' class.

Comment: I did add that and it didn't do anything. maybe the way I added it? film:Film under the public films: Film[] = []; ?

Comment: Why did you change the code to load film to `this.filmService.getFilms(id).then(this.route.snapshot.params.id);` ?

Comment: to see if it would work as I was trying everything, it didn't work

Comment: would it be working correctly using `this.filmService.getFilms(id).then(film => this.film = film);`

Comment: i did change it back and it didn't work... I have no clue why it not work, maybe missing a node module, directive, or something. Is there anything else i can do?